# Firebase database javascript set() not writing

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have this javascript function as I am working on making a web app (preferring to do it from scratch to learn JavaScript). For some reason, the database is never updated, no errors are thrown, and I can confirm that the `string` `displayName` equals a non-null `string`. Everything goes through and it navigates me to the website where I have it set to `"TO_LOGIIN (ANY URL)"`. No errors are thrown, no where in my database is something populated, but I get the email verification, I get the success status from the updateProfile, and the success status of setting the data - am I missing some syntax? I basically want to create a new child node at: `root/Users/uid` and instead that node have a key-value `Player Name: displayName` - in this case `displayName` is equal to Test. I feel like this is a syntax issue.

```
function createUserAccount(email, password, displayName){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {
        //Registration is successful
        user.sendEmailVerification();
        user.updateProfile({
            displayName: displayName
          }).then(function() {
            //Profile update is successful
            var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
            var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
            var userRef = rootRef.child('Users/' + userId);

            userRef.set({
                name: displayName,
                "Player Name": displayName
              }).then(function() {
                  location.href = "TO_LOGIN (ANY URL)";
              }).catch(function(errpr) {
                  // An error happened.
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log("error code: " + errorCode);
                console.log("error message: " + errorMessage);
              });            
          }).catch(function(error) {
            // An error happened.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log("error code: " + errorCode);
            console.log("error message: " + errorMessage);
          });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log("error code: " + errorCode);
        console.log("error message: " + errorMessage);
        $("#loginError").show().text(errorMessage);
      });
}
```

Here are the Firebase database rules I have setup. Let it be known I have an Android and iOS app that uses this same database and I am able to call the exact same function to create the data in the exact same place.
Edit, Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      ".read": "true",
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "true",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `userId` is used before it is defined?

Comment: Oops, fixed it. Still no luck.

Comment: How are your security rules set?

Comment: Added rules to the original post. Does the web work differently then iOS or Android would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got it working - I changed `set` to `update` and it works flawlessly every time now. I am not sure why `set` doesn't not create a new node, but `update` does...